# How do I pass props to a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Apologies for the, 'Please find the bug in my code' question, but I'm struggling trying to get to grips with React.

I'm trying to pass a variable named `hashRoute` to a component in react, but whenever I try to access the prop using `this.props.route` within the component render method, I get a browser warning saying:

> "Warning: Unknown prop `route` on  tag. Remove this prop from the
>   element.

My Component:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var Child;
        switch(this.props.route)
        {
            case 'about':
                Child = about;
                break;
            default: 
                Child = Home;
                break;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <Child/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Calling function:

```
function render(){
    var hashRoute = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    ReactDOM.render(<app route = {hashRoute} />, document.getElementById('app'));
}

window.addEventListener('hashChange', render);
```

I'm obviously ddoing something wrong, but I'm not entirely sure what. I've also tried using the spread syntax (replacing `<app route = {hashRoute} />` with `<app {...hashRoute} />` but then I get another browser warning telling me that `React.__spread is deprecated and should not be used.`

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little-known fact about React components: The name of your component MUST start with an uppercase letter.  This is to differentiate from the components in React reserved for HTML (like div, span, etc).

Comment: Wow. You'd think that's something they'd document. In big letters. On every page. Flashing.

Comment: It is documented; but not where you'd think.  It's in the JSX section, not the component section.  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized